# Why is the sort in lisp faster for lists than arrays?

Tags: arrays, list, lisp

I thought I should prefer list when the sequence is processed sequentially, and prefer array if I need to access elements randomly.

So, I write a few lines of code to confirm my thoughts. First, I wrote a function to test point multiple. And it shows It runs quicker in list.

But then I tried sort function. Since sort function need to access elements randomly, I expect It will run faster in array. But the result is opposite.

```
(defun test-performance-map-mapcar ()
  (let* ((lst (generate-random 1000000))
     (arr (lst-to-arr lst)))
    (time (atom (sort lst #'>)))
    (time (atom (sort arr #'>)))))
```

So, is it sort function applies some sort of  algorithm to adapt to list or list is really far more efficient then array in lisp?

Comment: What's the sort algorithm then? Generally, mergesort is easier to implement efficiently on linked lists than on arrays.

Comment: Also, arrays (arraylists) are no slower at sequential access than lists. (Probably faster because of locality of reference.) What they're slower at are insertions and deletions. Linked lists are the better choice in far fewer use cases than Algorithms 101 would have you believe.

Comment: @millimoose Indeed, this is why deques are (in general) better than linked lists for use as queues or the like.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: I might be confused, but aren't deques the same as doubly-linked lists? Same basic performance characteristics. (Of course, singly linked lists are terrible at queues.)

Comment: @millimoose Nope, see [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) for a description of one. Also, it says: "This class is likely to be faster than `Stack` when used as a stack, and faster than `LinkedList` when used as a queue."

Comment: Is it? Lisp has multitudes of implementations on widely different computers. You have posted a fragment of some code, but not an indication of actual results, which Lisp or which computer type.

Comment: http://jorgetavares.com/2012/02/02/sorting-algorithms-used-in-the-cl-implementations/

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce it.

Sorting vectors of random numbers is faster than sorting lists of random numbers in LispWorks.

```
(defun test ()
  (let* ((list (loop repeat 10000000 collect (random 1000000)))
         (vector (coerce list 'vector)))
    (time (sort list #'>))
    (time (sort vector #'>))
    (values)))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 9 > (test)
Timing the evaluation of (SORT LIST (FUNCTION >))

User time    =        8.697
System time  =        0.027
Elapsed time =        8.626
Allocation   = 170168 bytes
145 Page faults
Timing the evaluation of (SORT VECTOR (FUNCTION >))

User time    =        5.951
System time  =        0.018
Elapsed time =        5.904
Allocation   = 120512 bytes
86 Page faults
```

5.951 seconds for a vector vs. 8.697 for a list.

In Common Lisp one-dimensional arrays are exactly vectors. `SORT` does also not work on other, multi-dimensional, arrays.

```
CL-USER 10 > (vector 'a 'b 'c)
#(A B C)

CL-USER 11 > (describe *)

#(A B C) is a (SIMPLE-VECTOR 3)
0      A
1      B
2      C

CL-USER 12 > (arrayp **)
T

CL-USER 13 > (typep (vector 'a 'b 'c) '(array symbol (3)))
T
```

So a vector of three symbols is also a one-dimensional array of length three with element-type `SYMBOL`.

For my example (Apple Macbook Air with Intel i7 processor):

```
Implementation   | faster | seconds
-----------------+--------+--------
LispWorks 64bit  | vector |  5.951
Clozure CL 64bit | vector |  6.727
SBCL 1.1 64bit   | list   |  8.890
CLISP            | list   | 42.968
```

Comment: You have a much faster machine than me; your code ran in `39.352 seconds of real time` for the list and `42.882 seconds of real time` for the vector under SBCL 1.0.56.0. Shaving a `0` off gave me `2.512 | 3.256` in SBCL, `4.166753 | 4.528902` in CLISP, `3.140 | 2.040` in GCL and `1.958 | 1.689` in ECL.

Comment: @Inaimathi: I've added some numbers.

Answer (score 3):

On top of what was already said about arrays vs lists, there isn't such thing as "fastest" sort algorithm. This ultimately depends on what data are you sorting. Some algorithms will perform better on collections containing similar values, while others will perform better on collections that contain nearly sorted values.

In practice, there may be other complications, like, additional conses created during sorting or additional memory allocated during array sorting. Something that would necessitate a call to GC, which might absolutely turn over the tides.

Whenever you have a particular practical problem that requires sorting, you need to consider the circumstances and what kind of data you will be dealing with. For example, sorting of Z-vertices in a 3-dimensional space while rendering animations would probably most benefit from an algorithm that operates on linked lists and nearly sorted data, sorting of the meteorological research data will likely benefit from an algorithm that deals best with previously unsorted mostly unique data. Some particular software can do vectorized insertion sorting which will be many times faster then any single value per operation algorithm, and so on.

Sorting a collection of random numbers is usually a poor indicator of how your code will perform on actual data.